# How to scan for annotations in main sources when RoundEnvironment points to test sources

Tags: java, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I have created an annotation `@EnableEntityProcessing`that is intended to be used in the tests (src/test/java).
Also I have created the associated annotation processor `EnableEntityProcessingProcessor`.

The purpose of this `EnableEntityProcessingProcessor` is to scan for `@Entity` (javax.persistence.Entity) annotations found in src/main/java and to generate code based on these annotations. I would want the code to be generated under test resource because it meant to be used only in tests.

The main issue is that `RoundEnvironment` object points to the test code because the supported annotation is `@EnableEntityProcessing` (used only in tests).

```
public final class MyProcessor extends EnableEntityProcessingProcessor {
    private static final Class<EnableEntityProcessing> TEST_ANNOTATION_CLASS =
            EnableEntityProcessing.class;
    private static final Class<Entity> PROD_ANNOTATION_CLASS = Entity.class;

    @Override
    public final Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return ImmutableSet.of(TEST_ANNOTATION_CLASS.getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        final Set<? extends Element> elementsAnnotated = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(TEST_ANNOTATION_CLASS);
        if (!elementsAnnotated.isEmpty()) {
            for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(PROD_ANNOTATION_CLASS)){
                // code generation based on properties from classes annotated with PROD_ANNOTATION_CLASS
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the code sample, you can see that I am scanning for elements annotated with `EnableEntityProcessing`, and if one of the exists, then I want to look for classes annotated with `Entity`. The problem is that the roundEnv does not find them because it is linked to the test sources.

Comment: can you expand your question a bit? maybe some code as well, what is this `RoundEnvironment` and why it points to a class that is test code?

Comment: I have added a code example

Comment: I see, well i think since you are referring `@TestAnnotation` in your main code, it should be created there and not in test folder. even if you annotate test classes/methods, or use another annotation in your generated code, since you are generating it.

Comment: The test annotation (`EnableEntityProcessing`) is intended to enable the processing of elements annotated with `javax.persistence.Entity` from the production code. I do not want to have it in the main/production because it is only for tests. I have updated my post.

Answer (score -1):

You could implement your processor so that it gets triggered by `@Entity`,  apply it to the main code of your compilation unit but then use something like `target/generated-test-sources` as the directory for the sources generated by the processor.